# Change VSCode minimap colors

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can't find anywhere in VSCode theming docs how to change the colors of the minimap (background, highlight,...), can someone please help me with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fought this one for a while, turns out it's "editor.background" but you have to restart vscode for it to take effect.

Comment: From Review: Hi, this post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment.

Answer (score 30):

this works for me:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
   "scrollbarSlider.activeBackground": "#62fa1b",
   "scrollbarSlider.hoverBackground": "#fa2a1b",
   "scrollbarSlider.background": "#c97554",
},
```

[credit](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/26103#issuecomment-304913926)

(Keywords for google: VS Code make minimap lighter)

Comment: Brilliant. The default of "minimap.scrollbarSlider": "1% lighter" is such a pain.

Adding "VS Code make minimap lighter" for Google juice, to maybe help others save some time.

Comment: @SeanO Not sure I understood you correctly, I added your keywords for google in my answer. Feel free to edit/improve my answer.

Answer (score 24):

Starting in VS Code 1.43.0, you can change the minimap opacity and background color with the following setting in settings.json:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "minimap.background" : "#00002299"
}
```

I reached this by going to File | Preferences | Settings, typing "workbench.colorCustomizations" in the search box, and clicking "Edit in settings.json".

These are hexadecimal numbers and the order of the color channels is RGBA, so this example gives a very dark blue background and (full-size) characters from the editor can be seen behind the minimap.

Comment: Needful to say that the alphachannel of the background color affects the whole opacity and thus making even the foreground (text color) transparent, which in turn reduces readability.
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/92490

Comment: btw, great nick

Comment: You can also change the color for a specific theme with `{ "[your_theme]" : {"minimap.background": ...} }`

Comment: Try `#1e1e1e33`, it's the exact color of vscode's default theme background. The last two characters control the opacity.

Answer (score 18):

Here's how I sync up my customized minimapSlider and scrollbarSlider.

```js
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "scrollbarSlider.background": "#0000001a",
  "minimapSlider.background": "#0000001a",
  "scrollbarSlider.hoverBackground": "#00000028",
  "minimapSlider.hoverBackground": "#00000028",
  "scrollbarSlider.activeBackground": "#00000028",
  "minimapSlider.activeBackground": "#00000028",
},
```

Comment: We also needed `"editor.minimap.showSlider": "always"`. The setting of `"minimapSlider.background"` is what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

To always show the minimap slider (without having to mouseover) go to
File| Preferences| Settings and search (type in): "minimap show slider".

Change the default "mouseover", to "always".

Answer (score 0):

I think those settings can be overwritten. Go to your VSCode settings and under the `workbench.colorCustomizations` settings, the ones you're interested in are those starting with `scrollbarSlider.*`.

Check https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes for more infos.

Hope it helps

Comment: Yeah I already tweaked `workbench.colorCustomizations` but `scrollbarSlider ` keys don't affect the minimap :(

Comment: otherwise, take a look at https://gist.github.com/Hendrixer/7a250a2be529cda8939de8305c9a85a1

Comment: scrollbarSlider just affects the scrollbar sliders, not the minimap bg unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

```
  "editor.minimap.showSlider": "always",
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
      "scrollbarSlider.activeBackground": "#62fa1b",
      "scrollbarSlider.hoverBackground": "#fa2a1b",
      "scrollbarSlider.background": "#c97554",
      "minimap.background": "#252525",
  }
```